# Ethernet limited, light on modem flashing orange

Tags: networking, ethernet, modem

I am hardwired to my modem (Ubee DDW36C - provided by Comcast). On my modem, the port led my laptop is connected to is flashing orange (other ports that have successfully provided access to other computers are green). On my laptop (HP Envy, Windows 8.1), the ethernet is recognized, but it states it is *limited.* I have tried plugging into other ports on the modem, but they still flash orange and do not work.

I can access the default gateway, 192.168.0.1, from Google Chrome, but I cannot browse the internet. If it helps, the modem is on the first floor, and I am on the second. The cable from the modem provides a connection to my room's ethernet outlet, which I then connect to my laptop. The light on my laptop's ethernet port flashes white, meaning it recognizes the hardwired network (even though I can't access the internet).

What could cause this? How do I fix it? Do I need to somehow grant my laptop access from the 192.168.0.1 gui?

**EDIT:** This is the first time connecting this laptop to the network, but it works fine via hardwire on other machines in the house.

**UPDATE:** At 192.168.0.1, I can see my computer listed as a client to the modem, with a proper IP, MAC address, and interface, but I still have no internet access

Comment: Did it ever work? or is it the first time you are connecting this laptop?

Comment: @DeepSpace this is the first time connecting on this laptop, but it works for other machines in the house

Comment: Alright. The orange color simply denotes the connection speed (10/100 or 1000 Mb/s). This might simply be a DNS issue. Are you able to access http://212.143.195.20? This should take you to google.

Comment: You also want to make sure that your laptop's WIFI is turned off so it doesn't connect to an arbitrary wireless network. Being connected to 2 networks at the same time may lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: @DeepSpace Wifi is turned off, and I cannot connect to 212.143.195.20. It says "This site can't be reached. 212.143.195.20 took too long to respond"

Comment: Try to follow [these steps](https://support.zen.co.uk/kb/knowledgebase/broadband-changing-ip-address-and-dns-server-settings-on-windows-8), but choose Local Area Connection or Ethernet. In the Internet Protocol Version 4 settings, make sure both Obtain IP automatically and Obtain DNS automatically are selected.

Comment: @DeepSpace I tried that, and restarted the computer, but it still didn't work. I can still access 192.168.0.1, though

Comment: @DeepSpace Thanks for all your help, I figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

After resetting the router, restarting my computer numerous times, and waiting on the phone with Comcast and Microsoft customer support for *an hour* each, I simply turned off the network adapter for my VM. It seems the laptop was trying to use the network provided from the VM (which was not actually a network, but just appeared as one because it was a bridge between the host machine and the VM) in addition to the actual hardwired network, and thus could not resolve the two into one source.